# What is the substitution for partial property in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, properties, partial

I have an application (mvc 3) where the code is autogenerated for the datacontext class. And I need to expand the functionality, so I created partial class with the same name. But I found that only "void methods" could be marked as partial, while I need kind of a partial property.

So, is there any way to expand property's functionality in C#?

**Updated:**

Here is the code:

```
    public Table<Post> Posts
    {
        get
        {
            // writing info into Trace file
            Log = Console.Out;
            var result = this.GetTable<Post>();
            Log = new LogLinqToSql();
            SubmitChanges();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

The thing is that if I make any change to the data model this code will disappear, so how can I move it to the "safer" place?

Comment: why do you need a partial property?

Comment: cause I want to write the generated (by Linq) Sql code into log file

Comment: even if you can write a partial property, how will you intercept and access to generated SQL?

Comment: How would a "partial property" work?

Comment: @Jon, I updated code above

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi: This is exactly where a partial class shines. I don't understand what the problem is. You don't need to mark the property itself as `partial`. Just make the class `partial` and put the property inside "your own half". Of course the auto-generated half has to be marked `partial` as well.

Comment: @Jon: mabby I'm doing something wrong: I put the code above into "my half" of partial class and when the code is again autogenerated I get an error: the type "MyTypeDataContext" already contains a definition for 'Posts'.

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi: You are trying to replace the auto-generated `Posts` with your own version. This is not possible. You will have to tweak the generated code templates instead.

Comment: @Jon: so, every time the model is changed I need to refactor the autognerated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem (provide logging) is simple: In the autogenerated code there is a bunch of partial helper methods. And there is a method "OnCreated" which is called when the instance of MyTypeDataContext class is created. So, I just need to do the following:

```
public partial class WebStoreDataContext
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        // writing info into Trace file
        Log = Console.Out;
        Log = new LogLinqToSql();
        SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

If You want to add Attributes to the properties [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813320/setting-attributes-of-a-property-in-partial-classes) provides all the information)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for using the answer field, the post is for the discussion above:

Can't you just wrap the property from the DataContext in another property in your class

e.g.

```
partial class NewClass
{
    public Table<Post> NewProperty
    {
        get
        {
            DoHouseKeeping();
            return this.PropertyFromOtherPartialClass;
        }
    }
}
```

Only the classes need to be marked as partial.

Comment: this approach is possible, but I will have to change half of my code)

Comment: there's also another issue : You will have two properties exposed - one in your partial class, and one in the DataContext, and only the property in your class should be used ( ignoring the other one ).
This makes it quite non-intuitive